# Mac OS X Version 10.6.8

Tags: mac

I am trying to set up my printer HP ENVY 4520 to my computer and I am using a USB cord.
I have tried everything and I don't know where to go from here.  Is it possible for you to go step by step on how to hook up my printer to my computer?  I am not that familiar with computers but my friend owns a computer business and he is even stumped.  Is there an easy way to set it up.  PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: Why can't you just contact HP Support and ask them how to hook-up the printer?

Comment: quick Google says not going to happen... https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-Software-and-Drivers/ENVY-4520-with-OSX-10-7-5/td-p/5427027

Answer (score 0):

First, please edit your post to reflect the question (Setting up HP 4520, or some such) rather than the version of macOS you have.

HP has downloadable drivers for your printer [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-envy-4520-all-in-one-printer-series/5447920/model/5447921). With HP printers just Google the make and model of the printer along with "driver" or "download" to find what you need.

There is a problem though as the earliest macOS version supported is 10.8. You *might* be able to hack the installer to run and install on your version of macOS but I would bet that you still wouldn't be able to print.

You may be out of luck with this printer and your current version of macOS.